# SonarQube gets stuck analyzing one file

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I am trialing SonarQube.  Unfortunately it gets stuck analyzing one file before the build times out.

Is this normal?

```
2018-04-05T06:33:15.3622202Z 06:33:15.361 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:33:26.1234441Z 06:33:26.122 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:33:40.5878096Z 06:33:40.586 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:33:54.2365109Z 06:33:54.235 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:34:06.3436385Z 06:34:06.342 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:34:17.7346417Z 06:34:17.732 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:34:28.6925324Z 06:34:28.691 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:34:39.5986545Z 06:34:39.596 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:34:50.6177035Z 06:34:50.616 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:35:09.1436178Z 06:35:01.507 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:35:49.7682328Z 06:35:31.215 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:38:35.0662965Z 06:38:34.883 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:39:03.2274794Z 06:38:49.851 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:39:07.6807100Z 06:39:07.679 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 127,896ms last 8 cycles average is 15,987ms
2018-04-05T06:39:21.6860398Z 06:39:21.684 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:39:33.6476453Z 06:39:33.646 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:39:46.4008705Z 06:39:46.399 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:40:00.9056517Z 06:40:00.904 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:40:15.7915392Z 06:40:15.790 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:40:28.9217526Z 06:40:28.920 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:40:40.9808874Z 06:40:40.979 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:40:54.4799291Z 06:40:54.479 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:41:06.4147137Z 06:41:06.414 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:41:24.5070572Z 06:41:17.289 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:42:08.2295010Z 06:42:08.227 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:43:35.4594724Z 06:43:35.357 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:48:06.7983517Z 06:47:37.488 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 22,107ms last 8 cycles average is 2,763ms
2018-04-05T06:48:06.7986321Z 06:48:06.797 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:48:47.1840908Z 06:48:47.102 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:50:10.7776560Z 06:50:10.776 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 47,289ms last 8 cycles average is 8,674ms
2018-04-05T06:55:48.0152144Z 06:49:08.879 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:57:11.3161678Z 06:57:07.535 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:57:25.6523299Z 06:57:22.004 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:57:43.9775368Z 06:57:43.799 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:58:23.5000419Z 06:58:23.390 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 75,860ms last 8 cycles average is 9,482ms
2018-04-05T06:59:09.9334811Z 06:58:52.025 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:59:24.3235672Z 06:59:24.322 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T06:59:46.2992902Z 06:59:38.845 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 28,353ms last 8 cycles average is 13,026ms
2018-04-05T06:59:57.0392346Z 06:59:56.958 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:00:43.9534951Z 07:00:29.573 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:02:50.8318252Z 07:02:47.262 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:03:08.8264672Z 07:03:08.824 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 28,866ms last 8 cycles average is 16,635ms
2018-04-05T07:03:12.6319663Z 07:03:05.235 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:04:13.9638570Z 07:04:10.418 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 32,546ms last 8 cycles average is 20,703ms
2018-04-05T07:04:35.8399399Z 07:04:32.217 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:05:01.2058127Z 07:04:46.739 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:05:08.4602787Z 07:05:08.458 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 10,808ms last 8 cycles average is 9,027ms
2018-04-05T07:05:48.4033269Z 07:05:44.760 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:06:20.9405075Z 07:06:20.939 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3,644ms last 8 cycles average is 5,874ms
2018-04-05T07:07:26.4103851Z 07:07:04.593 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:08:42.5762495Z 07:08:42.454 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:09:48.2407719Z 07:09:44.573 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:10:32.1879298Z 07:10:32.186 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:10:57.9043693Z 07:10:54.293 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 148,805ms last 8 cycles average is 20,407ms
2018-04-05T07:11:12.8100332Z 07:11:09.064 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:12:47.9773973Z 07:12:00.237 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:12:55.2345425Z 07:12:51.590 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 14,615ms last 8 cycles average is 20,427ms
2018-04-05T07:14:48.6360933Z 07:14:19.328 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:15:12.0787483Z 07:15:07.945 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:16:37.2619876Z 07:16:33.470 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 98,670ms last 8 cycles average is 14,160ms
2018-04-05T07:16:41.0879899Z 07:16:29.830 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:16:59.1644084Z 07:16:51.848 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:17:06.6724507Z 07:17:06.483 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 11,036ms last 8 cycles average is 15,540ms
2018-04-05T07:17:47.2352481Z 07:17:47.046 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:18:42.2442650Z 07:18:42.123 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:19:04.0881661Z 07:18:53.125 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:19:07.7840387Z 07:18:49.415 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 14,786ms last 8 cycles average is 17,388ms
2018-04-05T07:19:45.0699857Z 07:19:18.876 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:20:55.1207962Z 07:19:56.101 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:21:27.9492422Z 07:21:27.948 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:22:00.7682972Z 07:22:00.766 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:22:51.9540403Z 07:22:48.254 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 36,730ms last 8 cycles average is 4,591ms
2018-04-05T07:23:09.9714187Z 07:23:09.970 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:24:22.7335118Z 07:24:22.732 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:24:37.4868262Z 07:24:33.868 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:25:13.8360317Z 07:24:48.425 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:26:01.3097842Z 07:25:32.147 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:26:19.5986928Z 07:26:12.267 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:28:19.4305175Z 07:28:15.685 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 14,395ms last 8 cycles average is 6,390ms
2018-04-05T07:30:04.6721338Z 07:29:09.932 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:30:37.2901290Z 07:30:22.761 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:32:04.4495014Z 07:32:04.448 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 130,555ms last 8 cycles average is 22,710ms
2018-04-05T07:32:04.6887099Z 07:31:27.900 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:32:37.1785529Z 07:32:37.090 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:32:51.6739183Z 07:32:47.919 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:33:17.1335848Z 07:33:02.482 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:33:42.7894674Z 07:33:39.037 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:34:12.1008030Z 07:33:53.729 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:34:23.0308348Z 07:34:15.740 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 58,297ms last 8 cycles average is 29,997ms
2018-04-05T07:34:44.8735352Z 07:34:37.521 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:35:06.9857536Z 07:34:44.872 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3,568ms last 8 cycles average is 25,852ms
2018-04-05T07:37:21.6702151Z 07:37:18.016 WARN: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 54,385ms last 8 cycles average is 14,531ms
2018-04-05T07:37:21.6703466Z 07:35:32.433 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
2018-04-05T07:41:05.1398350Z 07:37:32.703 INFO: 182/245 files analyzed, current file: D:\a\1\s\xxxxx.New\xxxxx.Web\xxxxx.Web\Scripts\lib\xxxxx-ui-kit\1.x.x\lib\kendo\js\kendo.all.js
```

How long does the analysis usually take?

Comment: Duration varies depending on actual codebase (but no reason for it to feel too long). Your log make me wonder though: do you actually intend to analyse this file ? it seems to belong to a library, so if this is not code under your control then you could/should [exclude it](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) altogether

Comment: I have met Kendo just once time, but I noticed its extremely big sized file, as you are having in the lib, so you are using it just like a dependency, you should to put it into exclusion

Comment: So - I deleted this question (i'm not sure why it's not deleted) because I figured out that it was running out of memory and that was causing it to stop.